# How to use Start-Process in Powershell to execute abaqus python scripts?

Tags: python, powershell, system, abaqus

I need to use Start-Process to execute abaqus python scripts in Powershell.
Usually, in cmd, I can excute it as

```
abaqus cae noGUI=xxx.py
```

And it works well, but **I could not find a proper corresponding lines with Start-Process in Powershell.**

**In Powershell, the mentioned code could still be executed, but with Start-Process, I could not find a solution.** Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Start-Process abaqus -ArgumentList "cae noGUI=xxx.py"
```

If it cannot find `abaqus`, provide the full path to its executable. If you get any other errors please add them to your question.